# How is a four terminal sensing compensating conductor resistances?

Tags: measurement, temperature

A [four terminal sensing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing) is used to compensate the resistances of the conductions. Why is that as I even use more conductions than in a two terminal sensing?

[image]

The current from the current source will flow through conductions which have a resistance and the voltage metering is also connected via connections.
So why are these conduction resistances negligible?

Comment: There is no current source in your diagram? Do you mean the voltage source or the current meter?

Comment: Indeed, the voltage source should be a current source, or not?

Comment: it doesn't really matter, since you're measuring both the current and voltage.

Comment: Do you realize that a connection/wire through which **no current is flowing** does not introduce a **voltage drop** and that a connection/wire through which a current **is** flowing, a voltage drop occurs? When you measure a voltage, do you want those extra voltage drops or not?

Comment: Through both wires is a current flowing!

Comment: @Ben, if the voltmeter has 1 megohm equivalent resistance, how much current is flowing through the wires connecting it to the DUT?

Answer (score 3):

> why are these conduction resistances negligible?

Because a voltmeter ideally has infinite resistance, and in practice is typically 10 megohms or more.

In the case of the current meter that means the current it measures is very nearly the same as the current through the device under test (DUT).

And in the case of the voltmeter it means the current through the leads that connect it to the DUT is very small, and therefore any resistive voltage drops in those leads is also very small.

**Edit**

In comments you said

> but I still have voltage drops in the conductions from the DUT to the voltmeter?!

Let's work an example. Suppose you're trying to measure the resistance of a 1 ohm resistor, and your interconnect wires have 10 milliohms resistance each. We'll use a 10 mA probe current. So the two measurement scenarios look  like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbdK48.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's assume our voltmeter has 1 megohm burden resistance.
Now in the 2-wire measurement, the ammeter reads 10 mA and the voltmeter reads .010199 V. So we estimate the resistance of our DUT to be about 1.02 ohms.

In the 4-wire measurement, the ammeter again reads 10 mA (being in series with the 10 mA source), but our voltmeter reads 0.00999999 V. So we estimate the resistance of our DUT to be about 0.999999 ohms.

The error in the 2-wire case is about 2%, dominated by the series resistance of the interconnect wires. The error in the 4-wire case is only about 0.0001%, from the effect of the 1 megohm voltmeter in parallel with the load.

Comment: Let's assume we use conductions with a length of..  100 m. The current should be decreased accordingly due to the conduction resistance, or? The voltage measurement I understand but isn't this always the case? The voltmeter has such an internal high resistance that I can assume no current is flowing through it?

Comment: @Ben, The current may be reduced slightly due to the conductor resistance. But the current you measure with the ammeter is still very nearly the current that is delivered to the DUT. Whether you can neglect the voltmeter's leakage current depends on the resistance of the DUT.

Comment: Is the voltmeter the only special part that plays a role here? Maybe I'm confused because for me I wouldn't measure voltage any differently..  why should I?

Comment: @Ben, In a two-wire measurement, you would be measuring voltage across the voltage source, so that any voltage drops in the wires from the source to the DUT would be errors in your voltage measurement.

Comment: but I still have voltage drops in the conductions from the DUT to the voltmeter?!

Answer (score 1):

Because current flows in wires 1 and 4, and real-world wires have resistance, the voltage at battery and load is not the same. But when the voltage at load is measured with separate wires 2 and 3, and very small current flows in those wires, you can read back the exact voltage at load. So 4-terminal measurement can be performed to cancel out wire resistance.

Comment: I'm confused such that I thought this is just a typical principle of voltage measuring?

Comment: Confused? Ok, take batteries and a lamp, and connect them with wires. Take a multimeter. Measure voltage directly at battery. Then measure voltage at lamp, and you will find that it will be lower due to the wire resistance. And if you move the multimeter near the battery while measuring lamp voltage, do you notice that you really are performing the exact same 4-wire measurement of the lamp voltage?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two circuits below, the left with two-wire measurement and the right with 4 wire (Kelvin) sensing:

The 1\$\Omega\$ resistors  represent the test lead resistance.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBI5Yd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the left circuit, there is an error of double the resistance of one test lead. In the right circuit the test lead resistances add no error at all, because there is no voltage drop to speak of across R6 or R8, and the voltage drop across R4 and R5 (which do carry significant current) are compensated for by I2 being constant. If I2 is not constant and we measure it, then the effect is the same, no error due to test lead resistance.

In reality R7 and R7 will carry a bit of current, but it might be nA or less, so the voltage drop will be utterly negligible.